# /etc/passwd minicom as the user shell with parameters

Tags: passwd

I have an application that I need to constrain the user to operate a serial console.

This works perfectly fine:

```
myuser:x:1005:1005:Someone,,,:/home/myuser:/usr/bin/minicom
```

However, I realize that I also need to capture the serial console, so I actually need to call minicom with

```
minicom -C somefile
```

And neither of these work:

```
myuser:x:1005:1005:Someone,,,:/home/myuser:/usr/bin/minicom -C somefile
```

```
myuser:x:1005:1005:Someone,,,:/home/myuser:"/usr/bin/minicom -C somefile"
```

```
myuser:x:1005:1005:Someone,,,:/home/myuser:'/usr/bin/minicom -C somefile'
```

I get an `Failed password for invalid user myuser from XXXXXX` error message.

I've also tried to leave `/bin/bash` as the shell in `/etc/passwd` and add `/usr/bin/minicom -C somefile` to myuser's `.bashrc` file, but the user can exit minicom and drop to an interactive shell, which I do not want.

I also tried to create a bash script

```
myuser:x:1005:1005:Someone,,,:/home/myuser:/home/myuser/runthis.sh
```

`runthis.sh`:

```
#/bin/bash

/usr/bin/minicom -C capture.log
```

But I get an `exec format error` when trying to log in.

Is there a way to call minicom from /etc/passwd with an argument?

Much thanks!

Comment: Did you miss the `!` in your script's "shebang"? it should be `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: OMG, I feel so dumb now... Thanks for the help!

Comment: You known you can get a shell from minicom with ctrl-A-J?